# SQL on Access. I am not sure on how to find the AVG price for my data due to it being needed to be filtered

Tags: sql, ms-access

The data I have I need to find the average price we bought or sold a ticker for the specific date. I will need it to filter by date, then ticker, then SIDE(buy or sell) and then find the avg of the prices.

The data is below:

```
ID  TradeDate   Ticker  Side    Quantity    Price
1   10/01/2020  WTRE    Buy 100 27.5
1   10/01/2020  WTRE    Buy 100 27.75
1   10/01/2020  WTRE    Buy 50  27.75
1   10/01/2020  WTRE    Buy 100 27.67
1   10/01/2020  WTRE    Buy 1   27.67
1   10/01/2020  WTRE    Buy 49  27.67
```

Comment: You should include the code of what you had tried.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
select tradedate, ticker, side, sum(quantity * price) / sum(quantity)
from t
group by tradedate, ticker, side;
```

This computes the "weighted" average, which is really the average price of each share.

If you want the average of the "buy" and "sell", then use conditional aggregation and arithmetic:

```
select tradedate, ticker,
       (sum(iif(side = "buy", quantity * price, 0)) / sum(iif(side = "buy", quantity, null)) +
        sum(iif(side = "sell", quantity * price, 0)) / sum(iif(side = 'sell', quantity, null))
       ) / 2            
from t
group by tradedate, ticker;
```

This assumes that each day and ticker has both buys and sells.

If not, just use `nz()`:

```
select tradedate, ticker,
       (nz(sum(iif(side = "buy", quantity * price, 0)) / sum(iif(side = 'buy', quantity, null))) +
        nz(sum(iif(side = "sell", quantity * price, 0)) / sum(iif(side = 'sell', quantity, null)))
       ) / 2
from t
group by tradedate, ticker;
```

Comment: Hey this exactly what i wanted. but what exactly is from t?

Comment: @john.doe . . . `t` is a placeholder for your table which the question does not specify.

Comment: For some reason i keep getting syntax error missing operator

Comment: @john.doe . . . There was a typo on missing closing parens.